# What does rootCategory in log4j.properties mean?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

`log4j.rootCategory` field in log4j.properties can have 4 different values, namely: `DEBUG`, `WARN`, `INFO` and `ERROR`.

Can you tell me which is most suitable for which cases?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the least severe to the most one:

```
ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF
```

If you choose one of them log4j will generate all messages of that type and of more severe type.

Purposes:

- `ALL`: generates all messages*
- `DEBUG`: debug messages
- `INFO`: information that aren't problems
- `WARN`: not error but something that could cause a future error
- `ERROR`: something went wrong, a problem that the application manages, the application could be stopped or not, usually must be reported
- `FATAL`: an error that crashes the application
- `OFF`: generates no messages*

(*) these are only keywords; for these categories there are no methods `all(msg)` and `off(msg)`, like we have `error(msg)` or `debug(msg)`.

Usually

- during development I set

  - logging on file to `ALL` or `DEBUG`
- when deployed I set

  - logging on file to `INFO` or `WARN`
  - logging via email to `ERROR`