# Apache commons+log4j Logging issue

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-commons-logging

I am having the below simple code. I am trying to use apache-commons+log4j since spring WS expects the apache commons to be used.

But I am not getting any thing printed. Please let me know what am i missing here.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
//Import log4j classes.

public class MyApp {

 // Define a static logger variable so that it references the
 // Logger instance named "MyApp".
 private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyApp.class);

 public static void main(final String... args) {

     // Set up a simple configuration that logs on the console.

     logger.info("Entering application.");
     //some stuff here
     logger.trace("Exiting application.");
 }
}
```

commons-logging.properties:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jLogger
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout, TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p [%c{3}] %m%n
```

Additionally I am getting below error message in console. I am wondering as I have not configured anything with slf4j

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be sure that your log4j version is compatible with the rootCategory key word beacause as i've found [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/200211.mbox/%3C5.1.0.14.2.20021116014110.036077d8@shell.visi.com%3E) it still exists just to ensure compatibility with the older versions so try to use rootLogger instead like this:
`log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout`
Other hand, you have a misplaced argument to your rootCategory
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout, **TRACE**

- Must provide only the least severe level and all the most severe one will be printed
- the seconde argument is the appender: you can provide more then one

see this post:[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933707/what-does-these-properties-in-log4j-properties-mean)

Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the error message when i wrote my answer, must add the jar slf4j-log4j12.jar to your classpath cause maybe you have slf4j api in your classpath and it contains the same package as common logging, see: http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/apache/commons/logging/package-summary.html